# "Fire Secure" menu item

Tags: plugins, security

I've got a strange menu item in a Wordpress instalation:

"Fire Secure"

[image]

If I click in this item, I got an error:

> plugins.php?action=activate&plugin=&plugin_status=&paged=&s&_wpnonce=&activated=true
>
> "This link expired".

Is it something to be worried? I runned a scan with Wordfence, and get no issues.

Comment: Disable your plugins one by one. Each time you disable a plugin, reload your site. You'll catch if it's a plugin conflict/error and you'll know the plugin in question. Can you remove it from your menu ? If yes, remove it and that's it, if not, let me know and we'll solve this issue.

Comment: Found it. It's a plugin to export learners from the Woo Sensei LMS. The "Fire Secure" is activated to insert the plugin  API.